# Watchkit new session does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I have two view controllers in my watch extension.Whenever I call

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:applicationData replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply)  {}
```

I get response only for the first view controller, and error in my second viewcontroller

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7011 "Message reply failed." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x79f1f100 {Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7010 "Payload contains unsupported type."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Only pass valid types., NSLocalizedDescription=Payload contains unsupported type.}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Message reply failed.}
```

WCSession is initiated in both app and watch extension.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by sending JSON string in dictionary format directly to the call back method from the iPhone app Appdelegate

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler {
```

instead of converting the JSON dictionary to normal dictionary.
And converting this JSON dictionary to normal dictionary in the watch viewcontroller call back methods

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:applicationData
                           replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {}
```

Since I was calling this methods from two different viewcontrollers in watch,sending normal dictionary from the iPhone app to watch works fine the first time but for some reasons I was getting the errors in the question if I send the dictionary from the iPhone app to watch for the second view controller of watch.

Answer (score 13):

In [WCSessionDelegate's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSessionDelegate_protocol/index.html) [`- session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSessionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WCSessionDelegate/session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:) method, the `replyHandler` argument is defined as `[String : AnyObject]`. The `AnyObject` portion is misleading. It can only contain a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html) data type: [`NSData`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSDate`, and `NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPropertyListSerialization). (Under these circumstances, it makes sense why `AnyObject` was chosen, since those 6 data types do not inherit from a common subclass besides `NSObject`.)

Usually people mention that [NSCoding and NSKeyedArchiver](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) can resolve the issue, but I haven't seen more examples/explanations beyond that.

The thing to note is that the `replyHandler` dictionary doesn't care about serialization. You could use NSKeyedArchiver, JSON, your own custom encoding, etc. So long as the dictionary only contains those 6 data types replyHandler will be happy. Otherwise you'll see the `Payload contains unsupported type.` error.

For this reason, you can never call the reply handler like so: `replyHandler(["response": myCustomObject)`, even if `myCustomObject` implements the `NSCoding` protocol perfectly.

Summary of encoding choices:

- NSCoding: The main advantage is that when you unarchive, it'll automatically find the correct class and instantiate it for you including any objects in its subgraph.
- JSON
- Custom encoding: One advantage is that your object is not forced to inherit from NSObject, which is sometimes helpful in Swift.

---

If you do use NSCoding, this is what it'll look like:

iPhone App:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(myCustomObject)
    replyHandler(["response": data])
}
```

Watch App:

```
WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage([],
    replyHandler: {
        response -> Void in
        let myCustomObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(response["response"])
    }, errorHandler: nil
)
```

Note that if you want to recover from a crash when unarchiving objects, you'll need to use the new iOS 9 API, [unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33380122/35690), which throws an error if there was a problem.

Note: Your custom object must inherit from `NSObject`, otherwise you'll get the following error when archiving:

> *** NSForwarding: warning: object ... of class 'Foo' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[Foo replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]

Answer (score 7):

"Payload contains unsupported type" likely means you are sending a custom object in your message dictionary. You will need to serialize this data to contain only the supported types (NSNumber, NSDate, NSString, NSData, NSArray, and NSDictionary).

I have a github project that automatically serializes your custom objects into safe ones for watchkit transfer. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/lehn0058/SwiftSerializable).

Comment: Yes,that was the issue.By the way it works perfectly if i send string but it throws an error if I do   NSString *str1 = [response valueForKey:@"d"];
            
            NSData *data1 = [str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            
            NSMutableDictionary *mainDict1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Comment: Do you have your github project in objective c

Comment: No,its not working second time,i calling the same method 2 times.

Comment: Where I can find the supported types please?  It just say it supports NSDictionary, but when I put an image in a dictionary as a keyValue, it unsupported.  <NSString *,id>means that key must be a NSString, but keyValue could be any object.

Comment: Convert image to NSData

Answer (score 2):

Using NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver you can serialize any object that implements NSCoding.

**To archive:**

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: entries];
```

Where entries is an array of objects that implement NSCoding.

**To unarchive:**

```
NSArray *entries = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

NSCoding is a protocol with two methods you have to implement like this.

```
-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)decoder {
  if(self = [super init]){
    self.yourpoperty = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"PROPERTY_KEY"];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)encoder {
  [encoder encodeObject:self.yourpoperty forKey:@"PROPERTY_KEY"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when accidentally transporting over 400 data objects to the watch. Limiting to 20 objects fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what happened before iOS 10 and XCode 8.0, in my watchkit app code i used:

```
let infoDictionary = ["request" : "word_detail", "word": self.word, "type": self.type]
```

and it works grest.
When I tested the same code in WatchKit app 2.0 simulator by XCode 8.0, I found watchkit connectivity error showing with unsupported format message.

After lots of debugging I found the solution for it:

```
let infoDictionary:NSDictionary = ["request" : "word_detail", "word": self.word, "type": self.type]
```

I had to put just NSDictionary as a typecast and the whole thing works without problem.